# FirebaseUI - Validate displayName before user creation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using `firebaseui-web-react`. In the signup flow, I want to validate the user-provided `displayName` before the user is created. In particular, I want to make sure the `displayName` is unique.

I know how to validate unique usernames with Firestore. I have a public `user` collection with `displayName` fields. I know how to see if a `displayName` is already taken, with a query like:

```
const snapshot = await store
  .collection('user')
  .where('displayName', '==', displayNameFormValue)
  .get()

return snapshot.empty
```

I want to validate the `displayName` before the user is created. I want to avoid creating and immediately deleting the user. I want to validate the `displayName` before FirebaseUI sends the request to create the user.

However, FirebaseUI only provides callbacks like `signInSuccessWithAuthResult`. These callbacks only run after the user has been created. If I use these callbacks to validate the `displayName`, I will have to retroactively delete a created user if their `displayName` is taken. I want to validate the user's `displayName` before they are created to avoid deletion.

How can I use the query shown above to validate the `displayName` before the Firebase user is created? How can I support unique display names while leveraging the pre-made FirebaseUI components and context? How can I integrate form validation with FirebaseUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's said in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/#customizing-firebaseui-for-authentication):

> Currently, FirebaseUI does not offer customization out of the box. However, the HTML around the widget is not affected by it so you can display everything you want around the widget container.

So you have no way to add a pre-hook, validation, etc. However, you can try to intercept the requests using [xhr-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr-intercept) or [fetch-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept) and do anything you want when there is a request for creating a user. You can cancel the request if the `displayName` is not unique and show an error via JS.

Answer (score 3):

As firebaseUI cannot be customized, the possible solutions can be.

1. Backend solution - Subscribe to firebase [hooks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that notifies any data change. where you can check for unique displayName.
2. Frontend Solution - Design a custom Auth UI screen integrated with firebase UI [plugins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start). Here you will have complete control over the data before sending it to firebase.

Comment: I don't see how you can use hooks to avoid deleting an invalid user, and the link you provided does not load for me. Can you explain the backend strategy?

Comment: updated bad link. This might help you - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#onwrite

Comment: Wouldn't onWrite fire after the user is record is created, thus requiring me to retroacitvely delete it?

Comment: seems like you need to delete it. I don't have much experience using firebase cloud function, I'm just exploring it with you. Check if writing rule like this might help - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe Firebase users created with Firebase Auth are not stored in a Firestore collection. You have to create your own "users" collection as I reference in my example code. As I understand it, the Firebase users themselves cannot be constrained with security rules. Thus I fear there is no delete-free "backend solution" as teimurjan says.